# Подключение ссылки на сборку Excel при работе с csc.exe C#

Tags: c#, excel

Пишу программу <s>на коленке</s> в условиях, в которых невозможно использовать IDE Visual Studio, поэтому использую обычный виндовый блокнот и консольный компилятор csc.exe.

Необходимо работать с данными из Excel-файлов.

При работе с Excel из IDE, всё ясно, подключаем ссылку на сборку, далее:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

и по сценарию.

Вопрос, каким образом можно можно подключить ссылку на сборку `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` используя только блокнот?

Comment: [-reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось действительно просто:

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace FirstApp
{
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

            excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            //Добавить новый Лист в Книгу
            (excelApp.Sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet).Name = "Данные";
            excelApp.Visible = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Далее в консоле используем такую команду для компиляции:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /r:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll d:\Excel\Excel.cs
```

Незабываем кинуть в папку с экзешником три офисные библиотеки:

1. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
2. Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll
3. office.dll

Найти их можно в папке с установленным офисом.